# Porque me da ese error

Tags: java

```
package es.upm.dit.prog.practica3;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class DetectorVehiculos {
    private static final int N = 10;
    Vehiculo v;
    Vehiculo [] detectados;
    int n;
    public DetectorVehiculos(Vehiculo v) {
        super();
        this.n=0;
        this.v=v;
        this.detectados= new Vehiculo[N];
    }
    public Vehiculo getV() {
        return v;
    }
    public Vehiculo[] getDetectados() {
        return detectados;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DetectorVehiculos [v=" + v + ", detectados=" + Arrays.toString(detectados) + ", n=" + n + "]";
    }

    public Vehiculo buscaVehiculo(Vehiculo v){
        Vehiculo aux= null;
        for (int i=0; i < this.detectados.length;i++){
            if (this.detectados[i]!= null){
                if (this.detectados[i].equals(v)){
                    aux = this.detectados[i];
            }
          }
        }
        return aux;
        }
    public void addVehiculo(Vehiculo v){
        int var1=0;
        int contador = 0;
        double auxT= Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
            for (int i= 0; i<this.detectados.length; i++){
                if(this.detectados[i]==null){
                    contador++;

            }
            }
            if(contador!=0){
            for(int j = 0; j<this.detectados.length;j++){
                if (this.detectados[j] == null){
                    if(v==null){
                    this.detectados[j]=v;
                    break;

            }
                }
            }
            if (contador ==0) {
            for(int w= 0; w<this.detectados.length;w++){
               if(this.detectados[w].getT() < auxT){
               auxT= this.detectados[w].getT();
               var1=w;
               }
    }
            }
            this.detectados[var1]= v;
            }

    }

**ERROR:**

arrays first differed at element [0]; expected:<Vehiculo [id=id10, pos0=Vector [x=10.0, y=10.0], t0=10.0, pos=Vector [x=10.0, y=10.0], t=11.0]> but was:<Vehiculo [id=id11, pos0=Vector [x=11.0, y=11.0], t0=11.0, pos=Vector [x=11.0, y=11.0], t=12.0]>.
expected:<Vehiculo [id=id2, pos0=Vector [x=2.0, y=2.0], t0=2.0, pos=Vector [x=2.0, y=2.0], t=3.0]> but was:<null>.
array lengths differed, expected.length=0 actual.length=10.
array lengths differed, expected.length=0 actual.length=10.
array lengths differed, expected.length=2 actual.length=0.
array lengths differed, expected.length=2 actual.length=0.
expected:<Vehiculo [id=vsad3, pos0=Vector [x=30.0, y=30.0], t0=0.0, pos=Vector [x=40.0, y=40.0], t=10.0]> but was:<null>.
expected:<Vehiculo [id=vsad3, pos0=Vector [x=30.0, y=30.0], t0=0.0, pos=Vector [x=40.0, y=40.0], t=10.0]> but was:<null>.
```

Comment: Hola @Rodrigo, podrías escribir más detalles sobre el error y de lo que quieres lograr, ya que con poner solo tu código no basta.

Comment: Pregunta duplicada https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/251394/porque-es-el-error te sugiero revisar [ask], saludos